# Inexplicable deferred tasks

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a fairly simple project on the App Engine. And somehow, a very large number of deferred tasks are created, and use up all my quota. In all my code (proven by grep ;)), I don't use tasks (yet), so I have no idea where the come from...

The task payload is as follows:

```
....sr.;com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.DatastorePutDeferredTask..(=.R.s...L..putMet.+Lcom/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity;xpsr.)com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity.c.<]..y...L..keyt.(Lcom/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key;L..propertyMapt..Ljava/util/Map;xr.4com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PropertyContainer..:<3.;....xpsr.&com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key....6E.....J..idL..appIdt..Ljava/lang/String;L..kindq.~..L..nameq.~..L..parentKeyq.~..xp........t..s~incoappt.._ah_SESSIONt.._ahshEQtxFwHEoPJXGuGBSXuUgpxsr..java.util.HashMap......`....F..loadFactorI..thresholdxp?@......w.........t.._expiressr..java.lang.Long;.....#....J..valuexr..java.lang.Number...........xp...8...Gt.._valuessr.'com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BlobV0.........[..bytest..[Bxpur..[B......T....xp...R....sr..java.util.HashMap......`....F..loadFactorI..thresholdxp?@......w.........xx
```

I noticed that _ah_SESSION is a part of the payload, and indeed, a lot of new sessions are created, but I don't know why.

About when the tasks are created: I have no idea... Not per request, or anything I could deduct.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? We are getting the same behavior with async session persistence enabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have [sessions enabled](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Enabling_Sessionshttp://) with an option to save session data asynchronously (via Task Queue):

```
<async-session-persistence enabled="true" />
```

Comment: Of course! However it still doesn't explain the fact that with absolutely no traffic (still a dev-stage-project), the task-queue explodes into thousands of tasks.

Could the fact that I have a security constraint have to do anything with it? This is part of my web.xml: 

 `<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>`

Comment: Maybe the http -> https redirect forces the task into a new session? Which has to be saved, as an infinite loop.